# What happens when I press Y while selecting two faces?

Tags: faces

When I select a face, it is light color, if I press the <kbd>Y</kbd> key, it becomes darker color.

Also, if I select two faces, the first face is dark color and the second face is light color, if I press the <kbd>Y</kbd> key, both faces will be dark color.

What does the <kbd>Y</kbd> key do in faces selection?

[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know what Blender has done after a key press, you can open a "info" window and look at the last operation that is logged:

[image]

Here this is "split". The mesh is splitted along the selected faces edges.

Comment: I can't find info icon, how to active it?

Comment: split the view and choose choose "info" as editor type (view menu, then area and split h or v)